# Trying to decrypt javascript code

Tags: obfuscation, deobfuscation, decryption, javascript

Is it possible to deobfuscate/decrypt this javascript code?

```
;eval(function(w,i,s,e){var lIll=0;var ll1I=0;var Il1l=0;var ll1l=[];var l1lI=[];while(true){if(lIll<5)l1lI.push(w.charAt(lIll));else if(lIll<w.length)ll1l.push(w.charAt(lIll));lIll++;if(ll1I<5)l1lI.push(i.charAt(ll1I));else if(ll1I<i.length)ll1l.push(i.charAt(ll1I));ll1I++;if(Il1l<5)l1lI.push(s.charAt(Il1l));else if(Il1l<s.length)ll1l.push(s.charAt(Il1l));Il1l++;if(w.length+i.length+s.length+e.length==ll1l.length+l1lI.length+e.length)break;}var lI1l=ll1l.join('');var I1lI=l1lI.join('');ll1I=0;var l1ll=[];for(lIll=0;lIll<ll1l.length;lIll+=2){var ll11=-1;if(I1lI.charCodeAt(ll1I)%2)ll11=1;l1ll.push(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(lI1l.substr(lIll,2),36)-ll11));ll1I++;if(ll1I>=l1lI.length)ll1I=0;}return l1ll.join('');}('fa31e1s212a27333718263o012z1o273z2q193x3e1b3q0z112m3o01202m3x3s37242v323n11203a251q273321162z2x23211c3s291z113a231s2535211432261y1110161z153x292q1731261s3u2t312p1z3w243e153v2b2o19312411101o253c1i2c2b38162x3s12111m380w121139233v313b36182v3u121z1o2c182v39233v2b233v3b213x2b213x1z113u2711203u291s3u271r2q1g27203q3e1x23121b3x1z1120243514312o1b3x1z1k1t35211b322n3e113u2o2z1q1g25311o1o251z1s253t193z26143e1e3c3b361c3y29341v3w2u3o3u37323b3p3720391914311411121m252c1q111z3w243e1d353a3v111z21141g1u1k181f1k1g1l1d1j3c181e1t3e1c1g1d3d143e1m3g1k1e1w1g141d172c1t2e102e1u2e112c1t2d1u2e1s1e152e1v2e1y2c1u2e152e1t3g1w2c1u2c1k2e1u1e1z2e1w1c1x2c1s3f1w2e1t2e1v2c1s2d172e1t2e1u2e1u2c1e2c1u2g1t2e1u2f1t2c1s3e1x2e1s3g142e1w2e1y2c1t3g1z2e1s1e1u2c1s2e1v2e1t2e1v2e1v2c1v2c1s3f1w2e1u3e1s2c1s3e1h2e1s2f192e1u3d102c1s2f182e1s3f1j2c1s1d172e1s3g102e1u3d172c1u3f1u2e1s3f1b2c1s3d1t2e1s2f172e1w3d1v2c1s3f192e1t3e1e2c1s3d182e1u3f1y2e1u3d192c1u3f182e1s1f1b2c1u3d1e2e1s3f172e1u3e1r2c1s2f192e1s3g1e2c1s3d192e1s3g1w2e1u1d172c1s3g192e1s3f192c1s3d1b2e1s2e1u2e1u1c1f1c1b2g1e3g1c1e1k1e1m3e1r3d1c3f1c3f1k2d123d1l2f1c2f1p1e1d3c1f3e1c1g1p1g1c1g1s3e1f1c1f1f1c3e1d1f181e1s1d1b1g1c3f1c3g1i3d1g2c1f1e1d1e1c1g1r3c1f1c183f131g1h2e1d1d1k1e1d1e1g1g1j3g1l3e1j1e141g1e3f1p1g1r1e1i1e1b2e1c1g1h3d1f2d1c1c1s2g1c1f1f3g143c1f3d1f1e1p3f1o3e1f3e181e1d1e121e1b1f1b1d1f1d1d1f1j1g1c2e1q2c1f1c1f1e1d3f1c1e1a1b1f1e1h1e1r2e1t3e102c1u2c1t1e142e1t2g1v2c1u3e1u1e1t3e1t2e1w3c1z2c1r1e1w3e192e1a2c1s1c141r123e161e1m3e1i2e1f3f142e1i3f1c1e1i1d1q2g1j1e123g1e1c1t3e142e1u2g1r2e1u2c112c1u2e1g2e1u3e1v2c1w2e1w2e1t3e1t2e1w2e1i2c1t2e1x2e1u2f102c1w2c182e1s2g1x2e1w2e1d2c1s1f162e1s3e112c1u1e1g2e1u1e1u2e1v2c1m2c1u2e162e1s2g1r2c1u1d192e1u2g1p2e1w1e1z2c1s2g1y2e1s3f122c1u2c1w2e1s1f1k2e1t2e1x2c1t3g1g2e1s1f1b2c1w3d182e1s3f192e1v3e182c1s1f172e1u3f1e2c1u2d172e1u3g1g2e1u3d1b2c1u3f1d2e1s3f1a2c1w3e1e2e1s3f172e1u3d192c1s2f172e1u3e1c2c1u3d182e1s3g1a2e1u3d1a2c1s3f1a2e1s1f192c1v3d1b2e1s3f192e1u3d172c1s2f172e1u3g1y2c1u1d172e1s3f1b2e1u3d192c1s3e1z2e1s3e1y2c1m1c123f1o1g1k1f163e141d142g1s2g1c1f163e123d1i1f1d3e1d2f181e1e1d1b1f1q3f1c1g1i3d1i1c1d1e1c1e1c1g1r3c1e1c183f131g1h2e1d1d1m1d1f1e1g2e1s2g1l3e1f1c1j3e1c2f1b1g1l1d1a1c122e192f1b2f1d1d1d2d1b1e181e1d3f1a3d173c1i1f1s3f1f2g1e3e1h1c1f3e1b1e191f1t1e1u1e121e1u1g143f1e3d191d1h1f1s2g1j2g1r1c1c3e181f1p3g1d1e1j3c1e1c1g2e1c1g1h2e1k1e1e3d1f2e1r1g1v2e1w2e1w2c1s2e1w2e1p2e1w1e1v2c1s2e162e1u1f1y2c1w1c1x2e143f183f172d1z1c191m2k1g1e3g1c1c1i3c1r1g1j1f1k1e1d3c1g1d1i1f1g2e1h1g1b2c152c1w1e1o2e1t2e152c1s1c1q2e1s3g1f2e1u2c1e2c1u3g1g2e1u1f1x2c1t2e1l2e1u2g1t2e1u3e1z2c1u2e1c2e1u1e1x2c1u2c1j2e1s1e1u2e1s2c1w2c1v2e102e1u2e1z2c1t2d1w2e1s1e152e1t3e1y2c1w2e152e1t3g1u2c1u2c1m2e1u1e1z2e1u1c1x2c1u3f1w2e1t2e1t2c1s2d192e1t3e1z2e1s3d182c1u3e1b2e1s3f192c1u3e1f2e1s3f182e1s3d1d2c1u2f172e1t3f1z2c1s1d192e1s3e1k2e1s3d172c1u3f162e1s1f192c1s3d172e1s3f182e1s3d1v2c1u3f192e1s3g1g2c1s2d1b2e1s3f1b2e1s1d172c1u3e1q2e1s3f192c1u3d1v2e1s3f182e1u3e1y2c1u3f172e1s3f192c1s3d192e1s2e1u2e1s2e1f1c143g193f1q1e1m3d1r3b1f3f1c3e1b2e1m3c1y2d1m3g1c3e1c1g1m3c1d1c1a3g133g1h2e1b2d1k1e1e1e1g2e1s1g1c3e1f1c1l3e1d1f1b3f1j3d181c142e193g1c1g1g3d1g2c1e3f1s1g1k3e1l1c1i1e1j1g1c2g1k3f1k1d1k3e1m3g1c3f1c3g1j1e1h3e161e1c1g1f3f1s3c1d1c1e1e1i2g121f141d1f2d1d1g1h3d1s2f1s2d1f3c1f2g143g1o1g1a1e1i3c1l1e1c1g1c3e1x1c122c1b1f1s1f1b3f1w1e1s2e1h3e152e1r2f1t2c1u2c1e2e1w2e1u1e1q2c1t2c1x2e162f1u2e1u3c1j2c1w1e192f1r3e192c153c191v1c2s1b2m1u1t2d1s1r1r14','d312em3q1v3s241a291u3b3x2z1d3q01121m27212q1b3v3e1k1b3x1z1k1c21193s3y1121161z153x3b2q1732261u3u2t322p113w243e153x3b2o192226113z1o252e1i3c2b381y2x3s11121o380w11122b233v312b381y2v3u11121o3c182v213p1z323a251s25352e16212v252e183u2711113a251q27352e162z381y1c3u271y2u29183s291u2u291o3e113w281z113w28113u263u2o3q0z11212b3y121o272e2q1z1z231411101o272e3q2m37222q113z312b233x3038163q011c1e2v2e2b2o142u11121d311q11313825373w273u273t15382111113a391z31161j111c1o2e182v3z2r2e2b233v312q1i29313e2b3y141m141j1e1e1d1e1e1h1e122f1m1e1e2e1m1e1a3g181g171g1m1c1k1f1f2e1s1f1t2e1v2e1t2e1s3e1w2e1u2g1g2c1u1e1z2e1s3e1t2e1w2c142e1s2g1p2e1w1e1m2c1u3e1h2e1u3f112e1u3c1z2e1t1f1u2e1u1f1w2c1s2e1u2e1t3g1x2e1w2c1v2e1u3g192e1w1f102c1t2g1q2e1s2f102e1v2e1l2e1t1e1u2e1v2e1u2c1s2e1y2e1s3e1b2e1w2e102e1s3e172e1v3g1v2c1s2f172e1s3f1z2e1u3d172e1s3f1b2e1u2f1b2c1s3f1a2e1s1f1b2e1v3e162e1s3f182e1u3f1x2c1s2f172e1t3f1e2e1u3d182e1s3f142e1u3f1b2c1u3f1a2e1s3f1a2e1u3d1h2e1s1f192e1u3f1f2c1s3f172e1s3f1v2e1u2d192e1s3f162e1u3f192c1t3e1i2e1s2f192e1u3e192e1s3f172e1w2e1w2c1s2e1e1e1f1e1r1g1e1c1k2f1d3e1b2e161e141e143f1s3f1c1g1w1f1y2d1j2f181g121d1e3g1g3e1m1e1b3e1c3f1l3g153e1l1e1i1g1h1f1i2e1a1c1f2f161g1s1f1l3e1e1c1g3g141f1h3g1b3g1e3d1s1g1m3e1c1e1e3f1e3d1f3f1f3f1c3f1e1f1d2d1e3f1e3f1b2g1u3e1h1c141g1s2g1f3f1t3d1e3d1f1e1f1e181e1e2g1d2c1c1g1b3f1g2e1e2e1e1e1k1e1d3e1g1f1i2e1l1d1t2e1s1g1j3e1f3g1a1c1d3g1i1g1f1e1i3e1w2c182e1s3e1s2e1h3e1w2e1v2e1u2e102e1h2f162c1u2e102e1u1e1h2f162d1y2f1x2e1h192g1h163e1h2f183g1r3e1c3e1w3e1c1g1i3e1j1e1q1e1j2c1a1d1g3f142e1w2g1v2c1w2f1r2e1s3g1z2e1u2e162e1u2g1y2e1v2g112c1u2e1s2e1s2g1x2e1v2c1x2e1t3e1v2e1u3f1y2c1w3e1q2e1s3g1j2e1u2c112e1s2e1e2e1u2e1k2c1u3e1z2e1u2e1x2e1w1d1t2e1t1e1g2e1u1f1z2c1v2e1m2e1u1g1x2e1v2c172e1u3e1y2e1u3e1g2c1w2e1r2e1s1f182e1w3c1i2e1s3f192e1w3g182c1u3f172e1s3f1d2e1u1d1b2e1s3f1v2e1u3f1b2c1u3e182e1s3f1b2e1w3e1d2e1s3f182e1u3f1a2c1u3f192e1u3f1x2e1u3d1a2e1s3e1c2e1u3f1b2c1v3g1d2e1s3f1b2e1u3e1m2e1s2f172e1w3g1e2c1u1f192e1u3e1s2e1u1d192e1t3e1i2e1u1f192c1u3f1e2e1s3f192e1u2c112e1s1e1k1e1a1f1m1e1l1g1f1e1i1f1r3g1t3b1e3g1f1f1b3g1j3g153e1q1e1i1f1h1f1i1e1a1c1e2f161g1c1g1l3e1f1c1i3f141f1h3g1b1f1e3d1u1g1m3e1c1e1f3f1u2e1r1e1b3e1c3g1e1e1r1e1e2g1j3g1d1e1u1f1r1e1r1g1m1g1p1g1e1g1m3e1a1e181e142f1f3g1f1c1r3e1f1f1g1g162g1e2c1i1e1d3f1c3f1e3e1k3c141e161g1k1f1j2e1u1e1s3f1f3g183g1m1g171e1m1e1f1e1d3f1u3e1e3d1u2g1l3e1d1e1y2f1m2c1u2e1u2e1s2f1z1e1w2c1v1g1f2e1t2e1t1f1v3c1j2e1u2g1j2e1u1f172c1b2f1r3f1f341l1r1m1e1c1e1m2g141g1g3g1h1d1e3g161f1i1g1l1g1t2c1i2g1y2e1r1g1i2e1u1c1u2e1v3e1k2e1w2e162c1s2g1r2e1s1f1b2e1u2e1m2e1w2g1x2e1u2g1y2c1s3f122e1s2e1y2e1s1d1k2e1t2g1v2e1v3g1g2c1s2e1w2e1s1f1t2e1t3e1t2e1u3e1w2e1u2g1e2c1u1e112e1s3e1t2e1u2c142e1u2g1p2e1w1e1k2c1u3e1j2e1u2f112e1s3c1z2e1v1f1u2e1u1f172c1t3e182e1s3f1a2e1u3d182e1u1f172e1u3e1b2c1s3f192e1u3g1v2e1s1d192e1u3f1b2e1u3f172c1s3g182e1s1f1b2e1s3d1g2e1u3f172e1w3f142c1s2f1b2e1s3f112e1s1d192e1u3g1w2e1u3f192c1t3f1d2e1s3f192e1s3c1e2e1u3f182e1v3f192c1s1f192e1t3e1b2e1s3d172e1u3f192e1u2e1u2c1s2e1y1e1f1e143e161c1k3g1d1e143e141f142e1s2e1d1e1q3e1a3e1f1c1g3g161g1h3g1b1f1f3d1s1g1r3e1d1e1e3f1s2d1m1e1d3e1d3g1e3e1m1e1f2g1e3g1c1e1u1f1f3c1d2f181g1s1f1d1f1j3d1f1g1i3f1g2e1e1e1q3d1c3f1l3f183f162e1a1c1f3f1e3f183g1e3f1m3c121f161e1e1e1f3f1s3d1i1g1e1g1p1g1f1e141c1s3f1r3e183e1v3e1f1e1g1g1k3f171g1g3e1l1c1f1e1e2e1s1f1e3f1m1e1f3e1m1g1p3e141f1s1c1w2e1v2f1s2e1t1f1y2e1f2e1w1g1t2e1v1e1w2c1s3g102e1u2g1j1e1s3c103e1t3e15141j2i2q1g2v2k1i2u1h1e1e161','562552b33313y351y371e27322q193v2e1d3q001z1o27213o2m273e2q2m2w253a1g232z1i3e2b361a2x3u113z1m280y113z39233x2139361c2x3u1z3z1o21182t3z2p112238231s27353c14212x253c1w2u29111z38251s27333c1631281w10111611133v3b2q192z341u3u2v2z3n113w263c133x3b2q172z2612111m23113w281z3u28113w261z3w2q2139213x3e2b213v2b233x252y3b3x2e1z1z2435163o00223e2b3w121o3e1d3o0z212m241z3z1o21111z3s2911211d393x3e1a1w10222x3w2s332e12111c1m11153x27211v322q12232722352c162835211d1e1a3e163z261y11121z302u2911101m3u37013z223516352e1g3f1l1g1k1d1h1e1s3d1h2g1q3f1f3e1a3g1m1e1g1e1h2f1e3c1u3f1m2c1r3e1z2e1u3e102e1v2c1w2e1s3f1k2c1u2e1a2c1q3e1r2e1u2c1s2e1v1c1e2e1u2e142c1w2e112c1q2e1b2e1u2e1g2e1v3e1h2e1s2e1u2c1u1g162c1s2g1r2e1s2c112e1w2c1e2e1u3e1t2c1w2g1y2c1r2e1t2e1u2e1i2e1v2c1v2e1u2f1y2c1w2e1a2c1q2g1x2e1u2e1d2e1u1d142e1u3g1v2c1u3f1b2c1q3f192e1s1d1a2e1u3e1x2e1s3f192c1u3e1k2c1q2f172e1u3d162e1u2d152e1t3f1o2c1u2f1b2c1s3f142e1s3d1b2e1w3c1a2e1s2f172c1w3f1f2c1q3f172e1t3d1e2e1u3d152e1s3g1b2c1u2f192c1r3f1z2e1s3d182e1w3e182e1s2f182c1w3g1x2c1q3f172e1s3d1b2e1u3d1s2e1s2e1u2c1h1e1j3d1e1g1g3g1u1d161g1u2e1b1e1i1g121d163f1i1c1e1e1s2g1q3e1e3e1l3c1d2f1b1g1j2d1a3g143c171f1f1g1g3d1i2e1e3d1q3g1k1e1o1c1k1g1j3d1a1e1h1e1b2d1m3g1a3d1d3e1a1g1g3e161f1j1c101e1a1e1a1c1c1e1c3e1k1g1s2f1b2d1d1f1r3d1d1f1g1g1d1d1r3e142c121g101e1c3d1e3g1m3e1r2g1s2e1d1d1c3g1u1c1q3e1g3f1e3e161f1k1e1q1f1g1e1u2d1j3f1e3c1d1g1k1e123e1e3f1i1e172g1v2e1t3c172e1u2c153e1q2e1r2e1t2e1v2e1u2e1u2g1r2c1t2g1j2c1v2f1w3f1w3c1u2e141q2g3g193f1q1c1b1e153e123e141g1i3d191g1g2e1k1e1x3g1i3e172e1v3e1v2e1u2e1v2c1w3g1b2c1u1f1y2e1t2e1s2e1u2d1y2e1t2g1o2c1v1e1w2c1t2e1s2e1s3c102e1u3c192e1u2g102c1u3e192c1t3g1z2e1s3c1y2e1w1c1o2e1t2e152c1u1e1q2c1s3g1f2e1u2c1g2e1u3e1g2e1u2f1x2c1v2g1l2c1u2g1t2e1u3e112e1u2c1c2e1u1e1x2c1w2e1j2c1s1f182e1u3d1c2e1u3d192e1s3f1a2c1u3f1b2c1u3f1l2e1s3d1b2e1v3c1d2e1s1f182c1w3g172c1s3f172e1t3d1f2e1u3d182e1u3g102c1u3f1a2c1s3f192e1s3d1a2e1u3c172e1s3f172c1u3e1f2c1s3f172e1s3e1q2e1u3d192e1u3f1c2c1u3f192c1s3f1j2e1s2d1a2e1w3d1b2e1s1f172c1u3f1d2c1s2e1z2e1s2c1m1e1j3c1c2f1e1e1h3b1e3f1e3c1b2e141e103b1f3g1a1d191f1f1g1g3d1i1e1e3d1c2f1k1e1o1c1k1f1j1e1c1e1h1e1b2d1m1f1a3d1c3e1a1f1g3d161g1j3c121f1w2f1j1d1a1e141b1d1g1e3f1p1c1d3e1e3e1j3g1e3f1e3e1g3f1g3c1c3f1f1f1k3e1m3f1y1e142e1e1e1b1c1f1g1j3d1p3e1y3g1c2e152e1c3d142f1f3e1g1c1k3e1e1c1s2f1m1e1c2e1d3f163e1d2g1i1f1k1e1j1e141e141e1a1f1r1e1d1e1g1c1z2e1t2e1y2c1t2e1w2c1f2e1u2g1f2c1w2e1q2c1f3e102e1u2c1v2e1u2e1f3e1s3e1t3c102f14121i1f1i1g1g3e1w1g1j2d191e1l1f191d1h1f1d1c1h1e1w1g1o3c1u3f1e2c1q2e1k2e1s3c112e1u2c1t2e1w1f1r2c1v1e1g2c1q1f1z2e1t2c1r2e1u1e1t2e1v2e152c1w2e1y2c1q3e1g2e1u2c1t2e1s1d142e1u2e1u2c1u2g1k2c1r3e112e1u2e102e1t2c1w2e1u3f1k2c1u2e182c1q3e1t2e1u2c1s2e1t1c1e2e1w2e142c1w2e1z2c1q2e1d2e1u2e1g2e1t3e1h2e1u2f182c1u3e1f2c1q1f1b2e1s3e1d2e1s3d162e1v3e192c1u3f172c1q3e1j2e1s2d1a2e1u3c1b2e1u1f192c1u3e1h2c1q3f1a2e1u3d1b2e1s3d172e1u3e1z2c1u2f192c1q3f1d2e1s1d1b2e1s3d1a2e1u1f172c1v3g1b2c1q2f1a2e1s3d1a2e1s2d152e1v3e1j2c1u2f182c1q3f1b2e1s3d192e1s3d1r2e1u2e1u2c1h1e1f3b123g1h2f181e1e2g1f1c1g1g1r3g1y1e1e2e1f1e1a1g1j1e1b1d1m1f183d1b3e1c1g1g3e161f1h1d101g1y2f1j3d1a3e121b1d1f1g3g1p1c1d3e1d3d1h3f151g1o1c1k1f1h1d1e2e1a1e1c1d181g1s1d1h3e1a1e181c1a1e181c1q1g1l1e1a1c1c1g123b1d1g1e1e1i2d1e3f1f1c101g163g1d3c1e3f1e3d1h1g1e2e192d161f1f1c1d3e1e2f1i3d1c1g1g1d1d1g1m1g1h2c1u3f1j3d132f1g3g142d1g2f1c1c1d3e1l2e1t2c1t2e1t3e1i2f1u2e1u2c1h2e1u2c1i3e1v2g152c1t1e1v2c1i3e182f183d1a3e1h122o1r2e1u1t2d2r1d2k2h221o','6fa51bac150ef9f7e25fbe006e71b61b'));
```

And please tell me how you did it, if you're a ninja and decrypted all that.

Comment: Try something, then tell us what and how you failed. Just don't ask us to do your analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `return l1ll.join('');` with `alert(lIll.join(''));` and the pre-obfuscated code will pop right out.

It's incorrect to call this a decryption.  It's just a de-obfuscation.

Comment: Not working.. It pop ups the obfuscated code anyways.

Comment: the code is obfuscated many of times. you should really just write a html page to print everything on it using `document.write(obj)` or something. Any way, the end result seems to be:
`(function ola(a){var important="m"
console.log(a)})("a")`

Comment: You should probably move this to an answer, since you unraveled the final value.